# Find $y$ for $(x\sin(\frac{y}{x})-y\cos(\frac{y}{x}))dx+x\cos(\frac{y}{x})dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$(x\sin(\frac{y}{x})-y\cos(\frac{y}{x}))dx+x\cos(\frac{y}{x})dy=0$$

$z=\frac{y}{x}\Rightarrow y=xz\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=z+\frac{dz}{dx}x$

$$(x\sin(z)-xz\cos(z))dx+x\cos(z)(z+\frac{dz}{dx}x)=0$$

$$x\sin(z)dx-xz\cos(z)dx+xz\cos(z)+x^2\cos(z)\frac{dz}{dx}=0$$

Multiplying by $\frac{1}{x}$

$$\sin(z)dx-z\cos(z)dx+z\cos(z)+x\cos(z)\frac{dz}{dx}=0$$

$$(\sin(z)-z\cos(z))dx+z\cos(z)+x\cos(z)\frac{dz}{dx}=0$$

I understand I need to get to an equation of the form $\frac{dz}{z}-\frac{dx}{x}=const$ can I multiply by $dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The DE
$$(x\sin(\frac{y}{x})-y\cos(\frac{y}{x}))dx+x\cos(\frac{y}{x})dy=0$$
can be written as 
$$x\sin\left(\frac yx\right)-y\cos \left(\frac yx\right)+x\cos \left(\frac yx\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
Now, by using the sustitution $y=zx$, we get
\begin{align*}
x\sin z-zx\cos z+x\cos z\left(z+x\frac{dz}{dx}\right)&=0\\[3pt]
x^2\cos z\frac{dz}{dx}&=-x\sin z
\end{align*}

Comment: I have got to $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{dz}{dx}cot(z)=0$ can I multiply by $dx$?

Comment: You can write it as $$\cot z\,dz+\frac1x dx=0$$